# Oracle connection problem

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to connect to an Orcle DB. This is my first time using Oracle databases( A MySQL guy here), and after the connection has been succesfully established, it throws and error:

```
12737 ORA-12737: Instant Client Light: unsupported server character set BLT8CP921 *
```

How would i go about fixing this? Does that mean, that the server has a charset not supported by my oci client, or what?

I am using PHP/Zend_Framework to connect to this db. As far as the Oracle version goes - I have no Idea. I was given only access to it, nothing more.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and add the version of the Oracle DB and the driver you're using and how you connect to it (java, command line, etc).

Comment: You could do the following query in SQL Plus to find out the version.

select * from v$version

Comment: How do I get it? And version is: Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
"CORE 9.2.0.8.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.8.0 - Production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fix would be to install Oracle Client Full or Instant Basic rather than Instant Light. You are right that that particular version cannot handle that character set and thats what is throwing the error, as explained here.

[Oracle Docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14294/install.htm) (scroll down to the header that says Instant Client Light)

Instant Basic is just as lightweight as the 'Light' version but supports all character sets.

Comment: As far as the link tells me, that would seem the only way to fix this, but sadly, in this case, I'm not the admin of the server, therefore, I can't do anything like this.

Comment: Theres probably more fixes out there but here we use Oracle Client full so I wouldn't know of them. Hopefully the fact that this has got some attention someone else more knowledgable could pick it up. Or you could stick a bounty on it of course. Good luck :)

Comment: @Janis: Even if you're not the admin, there has to be an admin. If that admin refuses to make the server usable by installing the software you need, talk to *your* boss about it so he can talk to *his* boss about it.

Comment: Thanks! Made the necessary contacts, and reinstall happened, all is fine now! Thanks!